# zsh completion ignored list?

Tags: zsh, zsh-completion

I have my .zshrc set up like:

```
CASE_SENSITIVE="true"
HYPHEN_INSENSITIVE="true"
COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="true"
```

In a directory, I have two files: C.c and C_1.c. If I do

```
ls C<Tab>
```

I get

```
ls C<pointer>.c
```

If I do a  again, it completes as

```
ls C.c <pointer>
```

So, my question is, why C_1.c is being ignored at all?
How can I have zsh prompt the selection for C* like bash does when I press ?

Thanks

Comment: In plain `zsh` these options do not exist. Are you using *oh-my-zsh*?

Comment: Yes, I am using oh-my-zsh.